# I am learning C sharp though competitive coding. I've got the solution with no errors but a warning. Here's a screenshot

Tags: c#, warnings

[image]

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string name = System.Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine(2 * num);
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CS8600  Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

I haven't tried anything

Comment: You can always [lookup the error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings#possible-null-assigned-to-a-nonnullable-reference) and read about what it is and possible ways to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can declare a class or struct as nullable by adding a ? after the type, for a class (string is a class) this means that null is an expected/acceptable value for the variable. Classes are essentially just pointers pointing to a value stored on the heap, null is a way to represent a pointer pointing to nothing and is usually used to indicate some kind of error. A variable of a class type can be null, but that may be unexpected, so we have nullable classes to show that null is a valid state for the object.

Example:

string name = "text";

string? nullableName = null;

If we removed the ? after string then the compiler would complain that we are trying to assign a value that is expected to be null to a value that shouldn't be null. Looking at the Console.ReadLine() method, we can see that it returns a string? and could therefore be null, but the variable name is only a string not a string?. The compiler knows that you want the string value and to throw an error if the result was null, but warns you that it may throw an unexpected exception.

Solutions:

You can tell the compiler explicitly that the value will/should not be null by using the null forgiving operator ! after the method call

```
Console.ReadLine()!
```

Declare name as a nullable string (string? Instead of string) and then check if the value is null, note that method that take a string will complain when passed name as it may be null

```
if (name == null)
{
    //do something in case of failure
}
```

If you are new to C# or programming in general, simply looking the error up on the internet will usually give the answer you are looking for when dealing with compile time errors/warnings. If you search for the error code (CS8600) you will properly see results from the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings) and they may be a little hard to understand so try and search for error/warning message instead in this case `Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.`
if you want to know more about nullability in C# I recommend [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-nullable-types/) article.